# A sufficient number of distances to recover relative positions of n points

Tags: matrix, computational-geometry, high-dimensional, machine-learning, geometry

On several places I found different claims on a sufficient number of distances to recover relative positions of $n$ points in $d$-dimensional space.

For instance, work from

http://www.dimitris-agrafiotis.com/Papers/jcc20078.pdf

(page 5, right column) claims that only $\left(\frac{n-d/2-1}{d+1}\right)$ distances are sufficient.

In another paper I found that $n(d+1) -(d+1)(d+2)/2$ distances are sufficient. Plugging in $n=3$ and $d=2$ yields different results (what about the result with the first paper?) What is the correct answer? A reference containing a more elaborate account would be appreciated.

Comment: The paper you specify seems to only state the second of your two claims about the number of distances.  Where did you find the first claim $\left(\frac{n-d/2-1}{d+1}\right)$ ?

Comment: I guess my statement was ambiguous. Another paper makes the different claim. Note that the first claim from your comment is in the paper, at p.5, right column.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the other paper?

Comment: @Paul Link: http://www.springerlink.com/content/0725vul28l764048/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $d>1$, you need to determine all distances of a simplex consisting of $d+1$ points, and then the distances from each other point to these points. ($d$ points and distances already reduce the possibilities to a finite number, but then one needs additional disambiguation information).

This makes a total of $d(d+1)/2+(n-d-1)(d+1) = n(d+1)-(d+2)(d+1)/2$ distances.

Comment: Thanks. You'd be surprised on how many places I've found the incorrect statement from the first reference cited in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The formula from the paper is a factor of $(d+1)^2$ times smaller than the second formula you mention.  Since the paper is only citing the equation as a well known fact I am going to have to argue that he simply mis-typed it, replacing the multiplication by $d+1$ with a division by $d+1$.  Also, the fact that it says $1/3$ of a distance is required for the 3 point, 2-D case doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: So, the second formula is the correct one? Any reference? Note that this author has mis-typed it once more: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3073873?uid=3737864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21100898925381  (p4, left column)

Comment: I see that you already got an answer so I don't know how helpful this comment will be.  I was simply making an argument based on the fact that they were different, so only one could be correct.  I was choosing the first equation based on the fact that it gave fractional answers to a problem in which only integer values made any sense at all.  I didn't have any reference for supporting the other equation as correct.